# Huge amount of Customer need to be import in short time

Tags: magento-1.9, import, customer-account

I am converting site from .net to magento. In the .net system there are nearly 15 lakh(1500000) customer records. I tried with magento default customer import method using csv. It takes 2 hours for 10k records.

So, I have written custom import function. Earlier it was working well. After importing 2 lacks records, the same time is problem coming now. Is there any solution to make fast in this situation?

Please advise my do to this thing in better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using magmi, it might work well for you - http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

The default import is not the best.